# Проверка на существующее значение в SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-edittext

Есть таблица **orders**(TABLE_NAME = "orders") и столбец **robotNum**(COLUMN_ROBOT_NUMBER = "robotNum"). 
Суть в том, что пользователь вводит число, которое должно сравниваться с теми, что уже есть в БД. Если значение в БД совпадает с тем, что пользователь ввел в поле **etRobotNum** (EditText), тогда всплывет Toast, - что значение уже есть в БД, если нет, то записываем новое значение.

*У меня программа вылетает когда ввожу число. Я неправильно сделал проверку, поскольку остальной код работает исправно. Хочу знать, что я не так делаю!*

**Фрагмент кода с проверкой**

```
etRobotNum.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

           orderCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + " where " +
                    DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ROBOT_NUMBER + " like " + s.toString(), null);

         if (orderCursor.getString(orderCursor.getColumnIndex("robotNum")).equals(s.toString())){
              Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
              "Значение уже есть в БД!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
              toast.show(); 
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }
  }
```

Comment: `orderCursor.moveToFirst();` перед ` if (orderCursor.getString....` попробуйте поставить. А вообще логи тоже приводите что пишут пжл. Проверку делайте на пустой курсор.  `if ((orderCursor!= null) && (orderCursor.getCount() > 0) ) {...`

Comment: @enizar197, И в Вашем примере проверкой на пустоту можно и ограничиться, так как значения Вы уже сравнили в запросе.

Comment: @TimurVI Спасибо!